# PHP function to find certain values in an array, then execute code

Tags: php

So I am trying to check to see if this array has an underscore in it. I am not sure if I am using the correct function to do this. Any input would be appreciated.

Some more info, if the array does have an underscore I want it to run the code below. This code seperates and gives me the attributes that I want. I also check if it has and S and then run some code. These are all output to queries which are then queried at the end.

```
    if (count($h)==3){
           if (strpos($h[2], '_') !== false)  // test to see if this is a weird quiestion ID with an underscore
               {
                    if (strpos($h[2], 'S') !== false)
                    {
                     // it has an S
                     $underscoreLocation = strpos($h[2], '_');
                     $parent = substr($h[2], 0, $underscoreLocation - 6); // start at beginning and go to S
                     $title = substr($h[2], $underscoreLocation - 5, 5);
                     $questions = "select question from lime_questions where sid =".$h[0]." and gid =".$h[1]." and parent_qid =".$parent." and title =".$title.";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     // there is no S
                     $underscoreLocation = strpos($h[2], '_');
                     $parent = substr($h[2], 0, $underscoreLocation - 2);
                     $title = substr($h[2], $underscoreLocation - 1, 1);
                     $questions = "select question from lime_questions where sid =".$h[0]." and gid =".$h[1]." and parent_qid =".$parent." and title =".$title.";";
                    }    
               }

           else
           {
            $questions = "select question from lime_questions where sid =".$h[0]." and gid =".$h[1]." and qid =".$h[2].";";
           }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the luxury of changing all the servers PHP code. I am just trying to figure out this one solution for the server.

Comment: I recommend you to use `stripos($search_in, $word)` .  Also what exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: You want to check one element or all element in the array ?

Comment: `strpos` is exactly the recommended function to use

Comment: @mackermann: That's why I said "new code". If this is old code, may god have mercy on your soul. If it's new code and you're using it "just so it's consistent with the old", shame on you. :)

Comment: @softgenic I'm not sure an underscore has a case to worry about insensitivity.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No offense but SIR!! `Old Is GOLD!!` :)

Comment: @softgenic: Not when it comes to ext/mysql

Comment: @jedwards well COrrect!!

Comment: Is the sql querry running ?

Comment: @jedwards if you recommend strpos, where is my code breaking? do you notice anything?

Comment: @mackermann I recommend you to mention the problems with the code you are experiecning

Comment: I posted a new comment on my answer - let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: I've modified my answer with a suggestion on how to proceeed.

Comment: I've updated again, run the script with the change and tell me what it outputs.

Comment: 2397 | 23981_1 | 23982_1 | 23983_1. so it is getting $h[2]. i guess the strpos function is just not written correctly

Comment: I've made another suggestion for the debugging. f you add in a print after the strpos line then we'll be able to see if that is the cause of the problem. I need sleep so I won't reply again tonight, but if you post the result then I'll pick it up tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strpos() is a good function to use when checking to see if a substring exists within a string, so your basic premiss is fine.

The haystack you're submitting to the strpos() (i.e. $h[2]) is a string , isn't it? You say in your question that you're checking if an array contains an underscore, but the code only checks to see if a single array item contains an underscore - these are two very different things.

If $h[2] is a sub array instead of just a string within the $h array then you need to iterate through the subarray and check each item.

so:

```
  for ($x=0; $x<count($h[2]); $x++) {
     if (strpos($h[2][$x], "_")!==false) {
         if (strpos($h[2][$x], 'S') !== false) {
            // Run code
         } else { 
            // Run code
         }
     }
  }
```

If $h[2] is just a string then what you have should be fine.

---

Update: try adding

```
print($h[2][$x].' - '.strpos($h[2][$x], ''));
```

on the line before

```
print ($h[2][$x].' - '.strpos($h[2][$x], ''));
```

This should give us an idea of what the problem is.

---

Update:

Based n the code we just ran things are very different from what I thought. First of all, not all of the $h arrays returned have 3 items. Secondly $h2 is a stirng, not a subarray.

so here's the new code:

```
  if (count($h)==3) {
     print($h2.' | ');
     if (strpos($h[2], "_")!==false) {
         print(' underscore was found | ');
         if (strpos($h[2], 'S') !== false) {
            // Run code
         } else { 
            // Run code
         }
     }
  } else {
     // array does not represent a question
  }
```

Also, you need to change all of the $h[2][$x] back to just $h[2]. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: would I have to do this for the strpos that checks for an S as well?

Comment: You already setup the iteration through the sub array so no. I'll modify my answer to incldue the check for S.

Comment: so it runs. however the underscore is not detected. an example of one of the $h[2] is 123451_1. Is there are reason the _ is not detected?

Comment: can you give a breakdown of the array $h[2]? It's hard to be specific without knowing what the array consists of.

Comment: the array consists of various question IDs these ids can be 123451_1, 1234SQ001_1, 12345a_1 etc... I want to get the number/letter just before the _ and use that as the $title variable, the rest of the question id (12345) is used as the $parent variable, then query it. in other cases I would use a function to get the SQ001 variable for the title

Comment: I don't see why the underscore wouldn't be detected.  If you modify your question to include the modified code you're using then I can check for you.

Comment: i have edited the original question to include the changes. I really appreciate your help

Comment: you need to change $h[2] to $h[2][$x] for all occurrences of $h[2] within the 'for' loop.

Comment: i edited it again to include those changes. For some reason it is still not catching the underscore

Comment: let's try some debuugging.On the line before "if (strpos($h[2][$x], '_') !== false)" - add the following: print ($h[2][$x].' - '.strpos($h[2][$x], '_')); then run the script and tell me what it prints.

Comment: 2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2. This is what it prints. Not really sure whats going on here. Could these be the $title variables?

Comment: well it explains why it's not detecting any underscores - there are none. Add 'print_r($h);' at the start of the code and add the result (or some of it if it is very large) to your question. That will get to the bottom of it all.

Comment: Array ( [0] => id ) Array ( [0] => submitdate ) Array ( [0] => lastpage ) Array ( [0] => startlanguage ) Array ( [0] => token ) Array ( [0] => 98226 [1] => 32 [2] => 2397 ) Array ( [0] => 98226 [1] => 32 [2] => 23981_1 ) Array ( [0] => 98226 [1] => 32 [2] => 23982_1 ) Array ( [0] => 98226 [1] => 32 [2] => 23983_1 ) here is what that returned. As you can see there are some underscores.

Comment: First of all, why are the first 5 arrays there not of the correct form (i.e. with three variables - the last of which being the question id)? Secondly, $h[2] is not a subarray - it's a string. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I updated it with what you suggested, instead I changed !=3 to ==3. The first 5 arrays are nonessential and do not matter at all. I am not worried about those. The other queries are still returned as false though

Comment: 2397 | 23981_1 | 23982_1 | 23983_1. so it is getting $h[2]. i guess the strpos function is just not written correctly